# What is the share of bad workers among the leavers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, bayes-theorem

There are $n>1$ workers in a firm, share $\phi$ of them are ''bad'' and the remaining $1-\phi$ are ''good''. During a given time period, a bad worker quits with probability $\beta$ and a good worker quits with probability $\alpha$. The quit events occur independently both across and within worker types. Let $1\leq k\leq n$ workers actually quit. What is the share of bad workers among those $k$ leavers?

Here's where I got so far. For $k=1$, the share is the probability that this one leaver is a bad worker, and is equal to $\frac{\phi \beta}{\phi \beta+(1-\phi)\alpha}$ according to Bayes' Theorem. For $k=n$, when all workers quit, the share of bad workers among them is clearly $\phi$. But what about intermediate cases?

Comment: I am not sure your $k=1$ expression is correct.  It might be $\dfrac{\phi \beta   (1-\alpha)}{  \phi  \beta   (1-\alpha) + (1-\phi) \alpha  (1-\beta) }$

Comment: I suspect you may be looking at a [Fisher noncentral hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_noncentral_hypergeometric_distribution) - not to be confused with a [Wallenius noncentral hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallenius%27_noncentral_hypergeometric_distribution)

Comment: Many thanks Henry!! I've checked the source you've recommended and got all the answers I needed. Very grateful to you.